# Get all element values with loop

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<ul id="div_choices" class="sortable ui-sortable">
  <li data-original-title="" title="">
    <div class="input-prepend input-append">
      <input class="input_choice_text" type="text" placeholder="متن گزینه مورد نظر را وارد کنید">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-original-title="" title="">
    <div class="input-prepend input-append">
      <input class="input_choice_text" type="text" placeholder="متن گزینه مورد نظر را وارد کنید">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I want to get the text of inputs with  jQuery. I wrote this code but it does not work:

```
alert($("#div_choices > li:first > input").val());

alert($("#div_choices li").first().children("div .input_choice_text").val())
```

This *does* work:

```
$('#div_choices li:first div .input_choice_text').val()
```

Now , I want to get all input value with a `for` loop , I used `children`, `eq`, `nth-child` but none of them work, why is this?

```
var node = $("#div_choices");
var node2 = $("#div_choices li:first div .input_choice_text");
for(var i=1;i<=node.children('li').length;i++) {
  var text = node2.next().children("div .input_choice_text").val();
  alltext += text + "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: You target the `input` elements as direct children of the `li` but they are not.. there is a `div` between them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use jquery eq method :

```
var $ul=$('ul#div_choices');
var $li=$ul.children();
var len=$li.length;
while(len){
    --len;
    console.log($li.eq(len).find('input').val());
}
```

> use jquery children method :

```
while(len){
    --len;
    console.log($($li[len].children[0].children[0]).val());
}
```

is helpful for you ?

Answer (score 2):

Try `jQuery.each()`

```
$("#div_choices .input_choice_text").each(function() {
    alltext += this.value + "\r\n";
});
```

Comment: I edited it a bit in the meanwhile. Current code should work. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.map()` method:

```
var arr = $('#div_choices .input_choice_text').map(function(){
     return this.value;
}).get();
```

`arr` is an array, if you need a string you can convert the array to a string using `.join()` method:

```
var str = arr.join("glue");
```

`.map()` iterates through the selected elements, using `for` loop you could do:

```
var $nodes = $("#div_choices .input_choice_text"),
    arr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < $nodes.length; i++) {
   arr.push( $nodes.eq(i).val() );
}

// arr.join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var node = $("#div_choices");
            var alltext = "";
            var mynode=$("#div_choices li:first div input");

            for(var i=1;i<=node.children('li').length;i++)
            {
                var text = mynode.val();
                alltext += text + "\r\n";

                var parent = mynode.parent().parent();
                mynode = parent.next().find('div input');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = $('#div_choices').find('.input_choice_text').map(function(){
     return this.value;
}).get().join('\r\n');
```

this will return a string containing values of all input elements(having class `input_choice_text`), each with new link I think you are for this. we can log this

```
console.log(arr);
```

and can check for blank value :

```
var arr = $('#div_choices').find('.input_choice_text').map(function(){
    if(this.value != '') {
       return this.value;
    }
}).get().join('\r\n');
```